# Apply the_content filter for specific post types only

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to modify a snippet of code I found here for a wordpress website: http://support.membermouse.com/support/discussions/topics/9000007386

Here is the code:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'restrict_mm_access' );

function restrict_mm_access($content) {

if(is_super_admin()){
    return $content;
}

$moreLink = '<span id="more-' . get_the_ID() . '"></span>';

$contentData = explode( $moreLink, $content );

if ( count( $contentData ) > 1 ) {
    $return = $contentData[0];
    $return .= "[MM_Member_Decision isMember='false']";
    $return .= '<div id="access-restricted-box">
                    <h3>You have to be a member to access this content.</h3>
                    <h4>Already a Member?</h4>
                    <a href="/login/?redirect_to=' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="button">Log In for Access</a>
                    <h4>Not a Member Yet?</h4>
                    <a href="/join/" class="button">Register Now</a>
                </div>';
    $return .= "[/MM_Member_Decision]";
    $return .= "[MM_Member_Decision membershipId='2']";
    $return .= $contentData[1];
    $return .= "[/MM_Member_Decision]";

    return $return;
} else {
    return $content;
}
}
?>
```

I'm using the [Member Mouse membership plugin](http://membermouse.com) to protect custom posts; so they are only displayed for paid members.  Our blog postings are publicly available.

The above snippet works perfect for protecting blog postings - which isn't what I want.  I want two custom post types protected (Tools, and Articles), and the blog postings to display to everyone.

I recognize that Custom post types are not posts - so there's the problem.  I just don't know how to modify the snippet to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: since this is specific to your plugin, you will have to ask the author

Comment: It is not specific to a plugin. The basic problem is WordPress specific and quite on topic. For a first question, this one is actually much better than usual.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever `the_content` is called, there is a global `WP_Post` object. So you can look into that to find its post type:

```
if ( ! in_array( get_post()->post_type, [ 'tool', 'article' ] ) )
    return $content;
```